# Qr code authentication using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, qr-code, firebase-authentication

I'd like to achieve WhatsApp web like authentication where the user should scan a Qr code using the mobile app to login to the web app using Firebase and I want to achieve this with users who are registered with email and password based authentication (I won't be using FB or G+ sign in's).

I've covered upto where the Android app could scan a Qr code and receive data,  I'm stuck on how to proceed to authenticate an user into the web app using the mobile app.

Any advice/pointers/sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Cesare I eventually did not proceed with it because I didn't find any solid information on this. I did some browsing on the topic for any updates and came across this: http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2016/09/20/how-to-implement-a-mechanism-like-qr-code-scanning-of-whatsapp-web/  HTH

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this I can think of would be to use Firebase Anonymous Authentication features. You could have your web app authenticate anonymously temporarily, generate a private and public key pair for encryption, display the QR code containing the UID of the anonymous account as well as a public key, have the mobile app scan the QR code and write the user's email and password (encrypted with the public key) to the Realtime Database to a location that can only be read by that anonymous account, have the web app decrypt the email and password and then sign in to the web app.

Obviously, storing passwords rather than just hashes is not the best security practice in the world but I believe a method like this could work.

Security Rules could look something like this (in pseudocode):

/Anonymous-user-id/credentials: read if user.id == Anonymous-user-id, write if userID is of any actual account.