# TV authentication with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, android-tv

I am building a TV application (modifying the existing mobile application) which allows users to authenticate to access more content. The existing native mobile applications (and API) use Firebase for authentication.

When signing in with Prime or Netflix on Android, a QR code is displayed which a user can use on their mobile device to sign in with. For iOS YouTube and Disney+ request access by asking the user to open a mobile app on the same network.

Is there a way to sign in a Firebase user in an application installed on a TV, using a separate device? We're looking for a better UX than using a remote and an on-screen keyboard.

The closest question I've seen is the following, but is ~5 and a half years old:
[Qr code authentication using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052272/qr-code-authentication-using-firebase)

Comment: What you’re looking for, is called “ OAuth 2.0 Device Authorization Grant” or “OAuth 2.0 Device Flow” (https://oauth.net/2/device-flow/). Maybe this project can help you out: https://github.com/PeaPodTechnologies/FirebaseDeviceFlow

Comment: Thanks @VincentBitter, I got going with a Github application, not quite sure yet how to get it going with Email/Password auth. I'm not sure if it's possible.