# Firebase - Email / Password provider device authorization endpoint

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement OAuth 2.0 device authorization for a Firebase project that uses the Email / Password provider for sign in.

In a response from a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072601/tv-authentication-with-firebase) I was able to test device authorization using a [Firebase Device Flow](https://github.com/PeaPodTechnologies/FirebaseDeviceFlow) project and the Github and Google providers successfully.

For each of these providers there is an endpoint that is used to request a device code:

- Google https://oauth2.googleapis.com/device/code
- Github https://github.com/login/device/code

Facebook has the following endpoint, which I have successfully tested:

- Facebook https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/device/login

Is there an equivalent device code authorization endpoint for the Email / Password provider?

EDIT: Looking at the firebase auth library I don't see a `credential` method that takes an access token. This implies perhaps this isn't possible. Perhaps something could be built to use the `credentialWithLink` method; an email would be sent with device id and the sign in would enable the polling client to receive a response with a link.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building the infrastructure myself by setting up:

- Endpoints: to get a device token, sign in to validate the device code, get a custom user token for a device token
- Website: for the user to enter in credentials to send to validate the device code
- Client app: to request the device token, show the qr code and poll for the user token and swap the custom token using the firebase auth method `signInWithCustomToken`

I used firestore to store the device tokens and update them with the uid, expiry timestamp and verification state with each step.